# window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() is empty on IOS 14.2

Tags: javascript, google-signin

setup login page

```
this.auth2 = window.gapi.auth2
.init({
client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
ux_mode: 'redirect',
redirect_uri: process.env.GOOGLE_LOGIN_REDIRECT, // https://domain/callback
scope: 'profile email',
prompt: 'select_account',
})
.then(() => {
let googleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
googleAuth.signIn()
});
```

in callback page
`window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse()` is empty only in IOS 14.2 but another version is work and android is work also.

Answer (score 0):

When ux_mode was 'redirect', it did not work unless ITP was disabled.
https://www.simoahava.com/privacy/intelligent-tracking-prevention-ios-14-ipados-14-safari-14/