# Google Cloud API OAuth2 doesn't work on any iphone browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a simple dashboard that requires the user to log in via gapi and grant permission to their Google Calendar. The code straight from the [Calendar Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) works perfectly on all browsers running on my Macbook Pro and Android, but barely reacts on any browsers running on my iPhone 12. I've tried Chrome, Safari, and DuckDuckGo.

If I clear data from one of these browsers on iOS, I'll be able to get to the Google login flow, but the redirect acts like nothing happened; `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()` returns false. After that, clicking the "Authorize" button (which should take you to Google login, if you're indeed not signed in) essentially just refreshes the page.

The only error message I get are the following warnings (Safari in iOS): [image: iOS Safari Warnings]

Here's the code:

```
function initClient() {
  let phoneNumber = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('number');
  if(phoneNumber !== null){
    window.localStorage.setItem('numberForNewUser', phoneNumber)
  }
  gapi.client
    .init({
      apiKey: 'API_KEY',
      clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
      discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'],
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      ux_mode: 'redirect',
    })
    .then(
      function () {
        let authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        authInstance.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(authInstance.isSignedIn.get());
        
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
}

let authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
let signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');
let profileContainer = document.getElementById('profile_info')

function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

function handleSignoutClick(event) {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
  document.getElementById('loggedin_container').style.display = 'none'
}
```

While searching around seemingly endlessly, I've tried solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231802/gapi-login-state-not-retained-in-users-browser-after-page-refresh), to no avail. Any other suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65283401/window-gapi-auth2-getauthinstance-is-empty-on-ios-14-2); redirect won't work on iOS, but popup does. Not ideal but good enough for now.